# How to implement http post timeout with last Rxjs version?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I used to set a timeout to my angular2 http post like following:

```
this.http.post('myurl',
      body, {headers: headers})
      .timeout(2000, new Error('Timeout exceeded'))
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe((stuff) => {
         //Do stuff
      }, (errorResponse: any) => {
        //Manage error
      });
```

But with last version of Rjxs (5.0.1) this isn't valid anymore.

Timeout need an Observable as first parameter and doesn't accept "new Error", how should I do/write that?

Thx you in advance for your help

Note: When I remove the "new Error(...)", my code is then valid but at runtime, I gonna face following error

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: _this.http.post(...).timeout
>   is not a function TypeError: _this.http.post(...).timeout is not a
>   function

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Got it, I had to include following:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout';

this.http.post('myurl',
  body, {headers: headers})
  .timeout(2000)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe((stuff) => {
     //Do stuff
  }, (errorResponse: any) => {
    //Manage error
  });
```

****** UPDATE for Angular >= 4.3 and Rxjs >= 5.2.2 ******

With the introduction of RXJS 5.2 the `timeout` operator could be done using the newly introduced `pipe`. Furthermore importing it as lettable operators might reduce the bundle size (in case all used operators would be imported as lettable).

Angular 4.3 introduce `HttpClientModule` which gonna at some point replace `HttpModule`.

Therefore here the updated code:

```
import {timeout} from 'rxjs/operators/timeout'; 

let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

let body = {something: 'my_value'};

this.http.post('myurl',
  body, {headers: headers})
  .pipe( 
     timeout(2000)
  )
  .subscribe((stuff: any) => {
     //Do stuff
  }, (errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    //Manage error
  });
```

****** UPDATE for Rxjs >= 6 ******

The above code still works fine in Rxjs v6 but the `import` or the `timeout` pipe should be modified like the following:

```
import {timeout} from 'rxjs/operators';

// same as above
```

Comment: Check question as answered, please

Comment: yeah this was a breaking change when they moved to 5.0 https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/commit/98ea3d221e0b1c2da66e09b525a165abfa7fb460

Comment: where is this 'Timeout exceeded' message now ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes You need to import

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout';
```

Fyi, you have other package to import if you need them

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout';
...
```

Comment: With Rxjs >= 5.2 timeout could be imported as lettable operators like `import {timeout} from 'rxjs/operators/timeout';` I updated my answer with an example